# Can't paint a custom component in Swing correctly

Tags: java, swing

I know Swing very poorly, so sorry for stupid question.
What I need to do is to make my custom components (they are ancestors of `JPanel`) with painting performed from the buffer (`BufferedImage` instance). It is a requirement, because the painting procedure might be very heavy, so paintComponent method is overridden to draw from that buffer and return imediately (but if you know better ways to tell Java not to repaint the object over 200-300 times a second consuming all the CPU - I would appreciate, maybe there are some public methods to mark regions of Graphics context as "not changed", so Swing does not try to repaint them).

What is wrong with my code that it simply does not draw data on overlapping JPanels. I have made a reproducable example of the core of the problem. See the code below:

```
public class Dr extends JPanel {

    public Dr(int x, int y, int w, int h, int fw, int fh) {
        left = x;
        top = y;
        width = w;
        height = h;
        full_width = fw;
        full_height = fh;
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    public void draw() {
        if (buffer == null && width > 0 && height > 0) {
            buffer = new BufferedImage(width, height, java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        }
        if (buffer == null) return;
        Graphics g = buffer.getGraphics();
        setBounds(0, 0, full_width, full_height);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.clearRect(0, 0, full_width, full_height);

        g2d.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 80, 128));

        g2d.fillRect(left, top, width, height);
        System.out.println(left + ", " +  top);
    }

    @Override
    public void repaint() {
        draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
    }

    private BufferedImage buffer;

    private int left;
    private int top;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int full_width;
    private int full_height;
}
```

This is a sample class that does nothing but saving his coordinates to draw at and full dimensions (which I want to be equal to its parent dimensions, that's a requirement again because I need to support visible overflowing content to be able to be displayed) and drawing a red rectangle with half of the 100% opacity.

Here is the outer code that uses it:

```
    Dr dr1 = new Dr(4, 4, width-10, 80, width-2, height-2);
    Dr dr2 = new Dr(4, 88, width-10, 80, width-2, height-2);
    root.add(dr1);
    root.add(dr2);
    dr1.setBounds(0, 0, width-2, height-2);
    dr2.setBounds(0, 0, width-2, height-2);
    dr1.draw();
    dr2.draw();
```

What is expected to be:

[image: what is wanted]

What is displayed when I remove my buffer and draw in `paintComponent` method directly:

[image: direct paint]

What is displayed when I don't fill the background (here the background has system L&F color, but I need the color of element's parent (in my example it is white)

[image: direct paint, no background fill]

What is displayed when I drraw from my buffer

[image]

The last one is completely amuzing. The red rectangle is partly cut off from the right and from the bottom, and the full image (including the white background) is clipped from the (0, 0) coordinate of the parent panel. The second object is not displayed at all. The coordinates in the console are absolutely OK.

I feel there is something I have to do with Swing to tell it not to perform its "magic" upon guessing what to paint and what not to paint. But how can I do that?

UPDATE:

I found that even if I don't call `draw()` method of my child components after I added them, they still hide their parent's background (which should not happen, bacase JPanels are meant to be opaque). So the core problem is that I can't make my `Dr` objects have opaque background (e.g. no background) where nothing is painted in them (it also explains why I see only the first rectangle - the z-order in Swing seems to be reversed, e.g. the last added component is painted at the bottom, as it was the farthest from us).

Comment: 1. Don't override `repaint` like that. The system might call that method, and the way you're overriding it breaks the Liskov substitution principle. 2. Call `super.paintComponent(g);` in your override of `paintComponent`. 3. The way you're calling `setBounds` in `draw` looks suspicious, but I don't know what you are intending. It's rarely correct to set bounds on a component directly, and certainly not when the caller is merely expecting a repaint. Instead, you should use a layout manager and then respond to size changes made by the system (if you need to) by using a `ComponentListener`.

Comment: We have a much easier time helping if you update your question with a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we don't have to guess about what the rest of your code is doing.

Comment: "and the way you're overriding it breaks the Liskov substitution principle" - why? when the system calls repaint method, it's OK to make a full force repaint. That is what I want. Do you think I will be repainting to often without the real need to update the buffers?

Comment: Call to super.paintComponent(g) did absolutely nothing. It seems to me that I should not use Swing mechanisms at all in my case (I'm making a browser rendering engine). One of the ideas is to store layers (`BufferedImage` instances) in a Vector in a special manager, and make my panel draw this layers in order of their z-indexes. And do not mess with adding child block elements as children of their parents (as nested JPanels) at all - anyway, I'm breaking the Swing mechanics by overriding things.

Comment: See the documentation for [`repaint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint--). Your override does something different. You need to at least call `super.repaint()`, but you probably shouldn't be creating an image and stuff in that method. You should also read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html

Comment: "See the documentation for repaint" - can you please tell me what the potential problems of my current solution are (maybe some that I don't see for this moment)? What will happen if I don't call `super.repaint()` in this method? And again - I added this call, nothing changed. Why the contents of my child components are not painted - that was the question. You suppose it is due to the override? But I need to override the default logic. No other ways, unfortunately.

Comment: When you don't call `super.repaint()`, the method *doesn't do what it's supposed to do*.

Comment: OK, I added that call, moved the `setBounds` call to constructor (there it will be more correct to have it, it was an overkill to place it where I placed it), added `super.paintComponent()` call at the beginning of `draw` method, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: If my suggestions didn't solve anything, then you need to post a more complete code example. There are probably issues elsewhere.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see now that I forgot to include the usage code from my JFrame class. I have updated the question.

Comment: Also I should mention that `root.repaint()` and `repaint()` calls in the outer code don't change the result on the screen in any scenario (direct paint or from the `BufferedImage`).

Comment: `root` is not a simple `JPanel`, it's also an instance of a custom class where paint logic is overridden (even in a more complicated way). But what is for sure - call to `root.repaint()` at least should repaint the background of the view area to white (and it was tested many times and worked fine). So I suppose that the children interfere with this painting somehow, that the background doesn't even show up as white (maybe the full-sized children (`Dr` instances) overlap the white background of `root` with system gray one when they are trying to paint themselves).

Comment: Oh, I have found some valuable information. When I comment out calls to `d1.draw()` and `d2.draw()`, there is still no white background. Even if I comment out calls to `setBounds()` in the outer code it will not change anything, because I have one more call to this method in the `Dr` constructor. In order to have white background I have to comment out `add()` calls, that add my `Dr` panels as children to `root` with full size of the parent.

Comment: What it means is that somehow my JPanels hide their parent's background - even though I have called `setOpaque(true)`, and moreover, JPanels should be opaque by default on my OS (in system L&F), as I have read here in some question...

Comment: And when I add the call to `super.paintComponent(g)` and leave the rendering code in `paintComponent` method, the result is even worse. I have two rectangles one upon another (it looks like a single one with 100% opacity) and still no white background from their container. Even when I call my custom method `forceRepaint` on the container in the outer code _after_ I add the children, the background does not show up.

Comment: *"What it means is that somehow my JPanels hide their parent's background"* - I suspect you don't understand how the layout management system works.  200-300 updates a second is roughly 3-5 milliseconds per update, you're going to find it pretty hard to sustain this no mater what you do.  60fps is rough 16 milliseconds - so some thought needs to be given to that.

Comment: The short answer is - Don't try to control the Swing Paint System - it is well defined and well documented. It uses a passive rendering system which provides you hooks into which you can inject your custom painting (ie `paintComponent`). If you want full control over the painting system, then I suggest you need to take a look at using a `BufferStrategy ` instead.  To be honest, I simple have no idea what you are trying to achieve and therefore no idea what to suggest to help you fix it

Comment: I don't know if someone said this, but you can't avoid calling `super.paintComponent` if you're also using `setOpaque(true);` - Swing could produce some weird paint artefacts doing this if you don't first take steps to replicate what the rest of the paint chain is doing...

Comment: "200-300 updates a second is roughly 3-5 milliseconds per update" - it was a figure of speech. I meant that by default Swing tried to update so often that it loaded CPU by 100% on one core (but I later found out that this was because I removed and added again my components in `paintComponent()`, so I understand that it was a heavy operation, I even wonder why I didn't get Stack Overflow error, because adding components procedure may also call `paintComponent()` on the same container where they are added).

Comment: "Swing could produce some weird paint artefacts doing this if you don't first take steps to replicate what the rest of the paint chain is doing" - my mistake again, I meant to write `setOpaque(false)`, because what I actually need is transparency and no background. But it seems that this line simply does nothing in my situation.

Comment: Refer below thread for better approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824808/jframe-painting-the-image-of-jbuttons-in-background/51837113#51837113

Answer (score 2):

So, what I "think" you have is a fundamental misunderstanding how, well, everything works in Swing.

You "seem" to be having an issue with how the layout management system works, how the painting system works and how the coordinate system works

Let's start with your `Dr` component.

You seem to want to develop overlapping components, which can show the child components below them, but you use `setOpaque(true);`, which means that the component won't be see through

This...

```
public void draw() {
    if (buffer == null && width > 0 && height > 0) {
        buffer = new BufferedImage(width, height, java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    }
    if (buffer == null) return;
    Graphics g = buffer.getGraphics();
    setBounds(0, 0, full_width, full_height);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    g2d.clearRect(0, 0, full_width, full_height);

    g2d.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 80, 128));

    g2d.fillRect(left, top, width, height);
    System.out.println(left + ", " +  top);
}
```

Seems odd to me.  You define the `BufferedImage` to be sized as `width` by `height`, but then use `full_width` and `full_height` to fill it...it seems, to me, to make more sense to do it the other way round

```
@Override
public void repaint() {
    draw();
}
```

Okay, important lesson in Swing, you don't control the paint process, so don't try.  Swing has a well documented and well established painting process that provides well defined hooks into which you can inject your custom painting (ie `paintComponent`).  If you need "control", then you need to look towards using a `BufferStrategy`, which will give you complete control to define you're own painting process.

Okay, so what's the answer?

Well, that's not so straight forward, because I'm not 100% sure I understand what the problem is you're trying to solve is.

But, let's start with the `Dr` panel...

```
public class Dr extends JPanel {

    public Dr(int x, int y, int w, int h, int fw, int fh) {
        left = x;
        top = y;
        width = w;
        height = h;
        full_width = fw;
        full_height = fh;
        setOpaque(false);

        setBounds(x, y, fw, fh);
    }

    public void draw() {
        if (buffer == null && width > 0 && height > 0) {
            buffer = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        }
        Graphics g = buffer.getGraphics();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 80, 128));

        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        draw();
        g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
    }

    private BufferedImage buffer;

    private int left;
    private int top;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int full_width;
    private int full_height;
}
```

So, here, I've changed it so that the panel will be positioned at the `x`, `y` position you pass to the constructor and will be sized to the `fw` and `fh` properties.

In the `draw` method, I then create a `BufferedImage` sized to the component's current size and paint ... what ever ... based on the `width` and `height` properties ... questions are raised about why we have to sizes, but, there it is...

The buffer is then draw to the top/left position of the component, this is important, Swing's coordinate system is based around the component itself, so `0x0` is always the top/left corner of the component, the coordinate system has nothing to do with the parent container.

*ps-* The red rectangle is for debugging purposes, you don't need it.

I then use...

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(new JLayeredPane());
        frame.add(new Dr(10, 10, 180, 180, 200, 200));
        frame.add(new Dr(100, 100, 180, 180, 200, 200));
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

And voila, overlapping components...

[image: Overlapping components]

Now, I strongly recommend that you stop and go have a read through:

- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html)
- [How to Use Layered Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

And, my gut feeling is, you probably really don't want separate components, what you want is one component which can paint many buffers

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try to use your code, but it may be difficult to integrate it, because when I do it it may suddenly stop working because of my other bad code. I will read about the BufferStrategy, OK :)

Comment: "but then use full_width and full_height to fill it" - no, you missed something, it was the opposite in fact. I used `width` and `height` for the painted rectangle, and `full_width` and `full_height` for sizing the component.

Comment: "below them, but you use setOpaque(true), which means that the component won't be see through" - sorry, my mistake. It should have been `setOpaque(false)`, I constantly confuse the words "opacity" and "transparency" when it comes to "true" and "false", though I often use "opacity" property in CSS and that is obvious for me. But however correcting that line of code didn't solve anything.

Comment: About the coordinate system - I know how it works. But I also found out that I can't display something beyond the component bounds, so that's why I needed my own coordinate system. That's why I need 2 widths and 2 heights. For now I think it was a bad idea, because if all my layers have full size of the viewport (e.g. screen, window, etc.) it will consume _lots_ of memory. I don't need to waste memory for storing transparent pixels, giving that only a few HTML blocks will have overflowing content (normal layout, or absolute or relative positioned).

Comment: I should better save layers as buffers of different sizes, keeping their coordinates. I mean, I need to do what does Swing, but without Swing (it really doesn't help here, only making a lot of problems).

Comment: "you probably really don't want separate components, what you want is one component which can paint many buffers" - yes, I also think I should do everything in one component, making it draw a vector of image buffers in the right order at the right coordinates. I tried to implement it, but now it simply draws nothing. Perhaps some code error again :)

Comment: I found the error in code. It was on the line where `ImageBuffer` was created. Thank you :) But fixing it didn't help to resolve the question completely. I either have a white background and only one rectangle (image 2) or both rectangles and gray background, which doesn't belong to the parent container (image 3).

Comment: Well, the screen shot was done based on the code I’ve posted

Comment: Thanks for your help, I finally figured out what stupid thing I have done when I have overridden `repaint` in such a way. I thought that I will just call `forceRepaint` where I need it, but in this example `paintComponent` method of children called `repaint` method of parent container, which I have spoiled :) And that explains why the call to parent's `forceRepaint` _before_ explicitly painting the children didn't help.

Comment: Better approach:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824808/jframe-painting-the-image-of-jbuttons-in-background/51837113#51837113

Comment: @SudhirDhumal It’s arguable and would really only be necessary if you want to support different look and feels, which has never been a significant requirement for my in the past

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue.

The problem was in the code that I didn't post here.

I added my `Dr` JPanels into `Block` JPanel. `Block` had `repaint` method overridden to draw from the buffer, but hadn't overridden `paintComponent` method in current version. It also had method `forceRepaint` to rebuild the buffer, and methods `draw(Graphics g)` and `draw()` to draw on the internal buffer or on the passed Graphics context, respectively. `paint` method wasn't overridden either.

As a result, after I added my children with call to `add`, Swing called the `repaint` on my `Block` object. But my version of `repaint` simply updated the internal buffer, and that was all. The result on the screen didn't change in any way.

So that was just a logical error.

The solution was to re-implement the overridden version of `paintComponent` in `Block` class, a class whose instance is the `root` object where I add elements.