# How to paint an image over the JPanel and add components in it

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

My application is a simple game of Brick Breaker. In order to paint the visuals of the application I'm using the paintComponent method. The application also has several buttons that are added using the following code:

```
levelMenu = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            double scale = screenSize.getHeight()/1080;
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.scale(scale, scale);
            g2d.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
        }
    };
    levelMenu.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel subPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(20, 2, 10, 10));
    subPanel.setBackground(Constants.CLEAR);

    subPanel.add(new JLabel());
    subPanel.add(new JLabel());
    for (JButton level: levelList) {
        subPanel.add(level);
    }
    subPanel.add(new JLabel());
    subPanel.add(back);

    levelMenu.add(subPanel);
    this.add(levelMenu);
```

The issue Im having is that the buttons are being added, but also they seem to be painted in the background image of the application: [image: example screen shot]

The buttons on the right dont work, and are just images. Any clue how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue comes down to...

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g2d.scale(scale, scale);
g2d.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
```

The `Graphics` context passed to the `paintComponent` method is a shared resource, all the components rendered within the paint pass will use it.  This means that any changes you make to it will also affect them.  You should be especially aware of transformations (like `translate` and `scale`).

A general practice is to make a snapshot of the state of `Graphics` context before you use it, this allows you to make changes to the copy with affecting the original, something like...

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
g2d.scale(scale, scale);
g2d.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
g2d.dispose();
```

The other issue is `subPanel.setBackground(Constants.CLEAR);`.  I'm assuming that this is a alpha based color.  Swing component's don't support alpha based colors, they are either fully opaque or fully transparent (although you can fake it).  This is controlled through the use of `setOpaque`

Now, I strongly recommend that you stop and go have a read through:

- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code snippet for your reference:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI;

class MyPanelUI extends BasicPanelUI {
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        Image img = toolkit.getImage("/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png");
        g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
        return super.getPreferredSize(c);
    }
}

public class PanelBGTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setUI(new MyPanelUI());
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.add(new JButton("This is button"));

        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

using paint component is not good practice so its always better to extent your component UI class from basic component UI class and override the paint() method. This way swing will take care of all the rendering / re-rendering part and your component(s) added to panel will be visible too.

Now, I strongly recommend that you stop and go have a read through:

- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)
- [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html)
- [How to Use Layered Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

Comment: I wouldn’t be using Toolkit.getImage, it’s to limited and I wouldn’t be loading the image every time paint is called - it’s to inefficient, in fact, the image reference should be coming from the component (or been set as a property of the UI delegate)

Comment: *"using paint component is not good practice"* - Really, says who? The tutorials you've linked to all support the opposite claim. Unless you're intending to provide different look and feel delegates, there's little point to going to the extent of developing a whole new UI delegate

Comment:  Did you really need to quote, verbatim, the last part of [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460644/cant-paint-a-custom-component-in-swing-correctly/49461312?noredirect=1#comment90628132_49461312)

Comment: Agree on loading image in paint method. Links in your previous post are helpful so had to pass the info. Any way everyone has their own perspective. But if you want to use paint component then in that case in few places you have to invoke the repaint / paint manually (which really depends on the situation). Swing just takes care of painting if you just provide the UI painter class with paint method.

Comment: Actually Swing doesn’t “just take care” of the painting - the UI delegates `paint` method is called by the components `paintComponent` method, so you’d still need to invoke `repaint` to trigger a new paint pass

Comment: No you don't have to invoke repaint manually (in your code), if you go for UI Painter class and if you are setting UI of the component before any frame / UI is visible on screen. (Constructor is better place to set the UI instance)

Comment: Neither do you have to for a component using paintComponent as (at least one) layout and paint pass is executed for you by the api - but, if you update a unbound property of either or add a component to the ui after it’s realised, you will need to manually execute a layout and paint pass regardless of which approach you use